# Locus of intersection point of tangents at extremities of chords of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Tags: geometry, locus

What is the locus of the point of intersection of tangents at the extremities of the chords of the ellipse 
$$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1\;\;$$
 subtending to a right angle at its center?

Comment: Please show you have  worked on the subject, explain where you are stumped...

Comment: Do you know for example that the tangent to this ellipse in $(x_0,y_0)$ has equation $xx_0/a^2+yy_0/b^2=1$ ?

Comment: Yes i know what you are saying. Actually i am not arriving at the answer. I know the answer but don't know the solution. Please help me if you can.

Comment: This question is on it’s way to being closed. If you’d like to prevent that, read [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466) and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Pole-polar relationships might provide a way to a solution. “Intersection of tangents” always make me think of looking at that.

Comment: Give names ! Let $A_1(x_1,y_1)$ and $A_2(x_2,y_2)$ be the chord's endpoints, How do you express the orthogonality of $OA_1$ and $OA_2$ ?

Comment: **Hint:** using results of my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864782/common-point-between-ellipse-and-tangent-passing-through-external-point/2865098#2865098) and also product of roots:

$$\frac{y_1 y_2}{x_1 x_2}=m_1 m_2=-1$$

you can find the equation for the pole $(u,v)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the endpoints of the chord $(a\cos\theta_1, b\sin\theta_1)$ and $(a\cos\theta_2, b\sin\theta_2)$. Then, the tangent lines at the endpoints are

$$\frac xa\cos\theta_1 + \frac yb\sin\theta_1 = 1\tag 1$$
$$\frac xa\cos\theta_2 + \frac yb\sin\theta_2 = 1\tag 2$$

Given that they also subtend a right angle at the center, their dot-product is zero,

$$a^2\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2+b^2\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2=0\tag 3$$

Take (1) - (2),
$$\sin\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}2
\left( \frac xa \sin\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2 -  \frac yb \cos\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2\right) = 0$$

which leads to

$$\cos\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2 = \frac{bx}{\sqrt{b^2x^2+a^2y^2}},
\>\>\>\>\>
\sin\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2 = \frac{ay}{\sqrt{b^2x^2+a^2y^2}}
\tag 4$$
Take (1) + (2),

$$\cos\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}2
\left( \frac xa \cos\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2 + \frac yb \sin\frac{\theta_2+\theta_1}2\right) = 1$$

Use (4) to get,

$$\cos\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}2 = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2x^2+a^2y^2}}\tag 5$$

Next, rewrite (3) as

$$(a^2+b^2)\cos(\theta_2-\theta_1)+(a^2-b^2)\cos(\theta_2+\theta_1)=0$$

Use the double-angle identity together with the results (4) and (5) to obtain the locus,

$$\frac{x^2}{\frac{a^2}{b^2}(a^2+b^2)} + \frac{y^2}{\frac{b^2}{a^2}(a^2+b^2)} =1$$

which is an ellipse.

Comment: But the answer is x2/a4+y2/b4=1/a2+1/b2

Comment: @user12076043 - Note that the two expressions are the same, with mine in the standard elliptical form